# Nginx convert URL to path on server

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a problem with converting URL into path to file.
For example. I want open file /var/www/html/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_one.conf in browser by link http://domain.com/dir1.dir2.dir3.file_one

Directories count can be a different. In one case 2 directory, in another 5 directories.

I've added mime type:

```
text/plain                            conf;
```

And configured location like this:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri.conf;
}
```

I can open file via link http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_one, but I need replace "." to "/" in path to file on server.

And yes, server has installed Nginx only.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You'd need a rewrite for that, and probably a complex one. Are you sure you can't fix the application so that it generates URLs with slashes?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change application. I searching rewrite but without results. :(